# warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List

Tags: java

I have been playing around and beginning to make my project, although at the very beginning I am getting the following error:
Main.java:21: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type List
network.getRouters().add(routerA); 
 And this error continues for all of my attempts trying to add a Router to the list in Main.java 
This is my Main.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Network network = new Network();
        
         setData(network);         
    }

    public static void setData(Network network) {
        Router routerA = new Router(1);
        Router routerB = new Router(2);
        Router routerC = new Router(3);
        Router routerD = new Router(4);
        Router routerE = new Router(5);
        Router routerF = new Router(6);
        Router routerG = new Router(7);
        Router routerH = new Router(8);

        network.getRouters().add(routerA);
        network.getRouters().add(routerB);
        network.getRouters().add(routerC);
        network.getRouters().add(routerD);
        network.getRouters().add(routerE);
        network.getRouters().add(routerF);
        network.getRouters().add(routerG);
        network.getRouters().add(routerH);

    }
}
```

This is Network.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

public class Network {

    private List<Router> routers;
    
    public Network() {
        routers = new ArrayList();
    }

    public List getRouters() {
        return routers;
    }

    public void setRouters(List routers) {
        this.routers = routers;
    }
}
```

And this is Router.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

public class Router {

    public int id;
    public List<Neighbour> neighbours;
    public Hashtable<Router, Table> table;

    public Router(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        neighbours = new ArrayList<>();
        table = new Hashtable<>();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

So that error doesn't like this part:

```
network.getRouters().add(routerA);
network.getRouters().add(routerB);
network.getRouters().add(routerC);
network.getRouters().add(routerD);
network.getRouters().add(routerE);
network.getRouters().add(routerF);
network.getRouters().add(routerG);
network.getRouters().add(routerH);
```

Why am I unable to insert a Router into a list, that has been declared as `private List<Router> routers;` in Network.java? This error tells me, that the List has a raw type, although that list does have a type which is `Router` so perhaps I am missing something here and I don't know what.

Comment: You're initializing it as a raw type: `routers = new ArrayList();`. Oh yeah, you're missing generics in a load of places.

Comment: `List getRouters()` should be `List<Router> getRouters()`. `setRouters(List routers)` should correspondingly be `setRouters(List<Router> routers)`.

Comment: @gthanop Thank you, can't believe that this was such a stupid mistake.